# Changing Wordpress content font

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm trying to change the font family of the content(the_content()) but when I wrap it with a `<P>` tag like this

```
<p class="naskh"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
```

And when I check it on developer tools on chrome the content is not inside the `<P>` tag, it's like that:

```
<p class="naskh" lingdex="0"></p>
<p lingdex="1"> the content ...</p>
```

so I can't give the content the font type I want. I searched a lot and tried many given solutions but non of them worked for me.
What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont wrap your `the_content()` in `p`. Rather you can do like this

```
<div class="someclass">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

And then in you css you can have something like this

```
.someclass, .someclass p, .someclass h1 {
    font-family: you_custom_font_family, Arial, Helvetica;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should not be the technical ans:

wordpress uses to filter text by default. 
 to remove filter you can use wordpress's function

you  can write below code

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

instead of

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

it will remove your auto generated `<p>` tags.

Thanks