# What does "lingdex" attribute mean? Is it related to HTML?

Tags: html

What is the use of it? As far as I have seen, it is used with paragraph tag only. There is no info about this on the internet. It looks like below:

```
<p lingdex="1">DEMO</p>
```

Comment: Where did you see this?  Maybe some JavaScript (or CSS) library is using it.

Comment: There is no such attribute in the current HTML standards.

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be `index` or `tabindex` and was misspelled?

Comment: exactly. there is nothing like this in HTML dictionary. But here are some links in which I have found this.                        https://github.com/grepman/JS-Coding-Ability-Test/blob/master/index.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358711/changing-wordpress-content-font